# I create flutter with api call but the data not showing at fresh install

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, sharedpreferences, access-token

So I create an app with rest API, but the data not showing on a fresh install

This is for gettoken and save to shared prefs

```
getInit() async {
    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/get-token";
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(myUrl),
        body: {'secret': 'code'});
    debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
    debugPrint(response.body);

    var data = json.decode(response.body)["data"];
    _save(data["access_token"]);
    // return data;
  }

  //SAVE TOKEN
  _save(String token) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    const key = 'token';
    final value = token;

    prefs.setString(key, value);
    debugPrint("new token save " + value);
  }
```

This for getlist item, need bearer access token from shared prefs

```
getRecList() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    const key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/home";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });
    debugPrint(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      List<ModelKost> modelkost =
          data.map((item) => ModelKost.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return modelkost;
    } else {
      return <ModelKost>[];
    }
  }
```

So every time I fresh install, home page does not show any data because getRecList item is forbidden access...

The log says token success, but getRecList fails because not get access token, it only happens on fresh install if I refresh/hot reload the list showing normally ...

so I guess the function getRecList wrong here, but I have no idea to fix it ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is you are not waiting for token value. use `await` when geting value from shared preferences

```
So I create an app with rest API, but the data not showing on a fresh install



getRecList() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    const key = 'token';
    final value =await  prefs.get(key) ?? 0; //use await here

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/home";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });
    debugPrint(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      List<ModelKost> modelkost =
          data.map((item) => ModelKost.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return modelkost;
    } else {
      return <ModelKost>[];
    }
  }
```

Comment: I try your suggestion, but the problem still happens...